# integrating paypal standards with multiple items in shopping cart using php

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal, shopping-cart

I have created a website http://www.mandyevansartist.com from php with a mysqli database and am now trying to integrate paypal into the checkout.

my latest attempt is

```
 $checkout = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart where cookieId =     '".GetCartId()."'");
while   ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkout)){
$num = "1"; 
$num++;
echo  '<br / >';
echo  'a '.$row['product'];
echo ' of '.$row['name'];
echo ' at '.$row['price'];

echo '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"    method="post">';

$count = 1;
$count = $count + 1;
echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_".$count."'  value=".$row['name']."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_number_".$count."' value='".$count."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount_".$count."'     value='".$row['price']."'>";


echo'<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@mail.com">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AU">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mandyevansartist.com">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';
echo'<input type="submit" value="paypal">'; 
echo '</form>';
 }
```

I have been through many different attempts in trying to get both items sent through to the sandbox payment page by pressing one submit button. This is day three and my more successful attempts were on day one and are now lost.

the result of this code is that the product,name and price are coming up from the database and being printed out with a submit button for each item - when pressing either button the result is 'error - empty shopping cart'

After adding a 'foreach' after the count I now have many repeated items going to the shopping cart

```
echo' <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  method="post">';

$checkout = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart where cookieId =  '".GetCartId()."'");
while   ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkout)){
echo  '<br / >';
echo  'a '.$row['product'];
echo ' of '.$row['name'];
echo ' at '.$row['price'];
$name = $row['name'];
$price= $row['price'];
$id= GetCartId();
$count = 1;
foreach($row as $id):
echo'<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AU">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@mail.com">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$count.'"  value="'.$name.'">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$count.'" value="'.$price.'">';
$count++;
 endforeach;
}
echo'<input type="submit" value="PayPal">';
echo'</form>';
```